# how to change button image in array list using button action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uibutton

```
-(void)createButton
{

    int row = 0;
        y = 340;
        int column = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.count; ++i)
        {
            x=column*110+10;
            for (y=340; y <= (x+ 90); y=y+320)
            {
                x=x-10;
            }
            NSString *imgPath = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *imagePath = [newPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgPath];
            myButton = [[UIButton  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, row*110+35, 80, 80)];
            myButton.tag = i;
            UIImage *buttonImage =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            [myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //        myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    //        myImageView.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

            [myScrollView addSubview:myButton];

            if (row == 2)
            {
                row = 0;
                column++;
            }
            else
            {
                row++;
            }
        }
        [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((column+1) * 110 + 10,372) ];

}

// in botton action
-(void)imageButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{

    NSLog(@"sender tag is %i",sender.tag);

    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

but it change last button image of myArray
i can get tag number

Comment: Are you trying to add button image using i value.please make your question a lit bit clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always get last button the way you have because myButton is the last button that you have.

To get exact button with use of tag, use below code

```
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];
```

Now you can set image to this button...

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you Fahim Parkar really it's work. thank you so much. but i clicked  button at maArray index 0 it's crashed please how can slove it help me

Comment: @rams : provide me what you have in mArray... and provide the detailed info of what crash is occuring...

Comment: i typed wrongly like maArray, that's myArray Sorry Please help me

Comment: provide me what you have in myArray.. also provide the details of the crash that is occuring...

Comment: In myArray 20 images is there base on myArrayCount buttons are created when i select index path 1 to 19 there is no problem but when i select at index path 0 program crashed. and show error like this:- ( unrecognized selector sent to instance) (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIScrollView setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa43af70'
*** First throw call stack:)

Comment: @rams : problem is at `++i`. change it to `i++` in for loop... this will solve your problem... If you don't understand why, let me know, I will explain you... just use `NSLog(@"i==%d", i);` before `x=column*110+10;` & then you will understand that it was causing as you reached i=20... you never have i=0

Comment: I changed ++i to i++ but it's not working.the crashed at button action, the sender.tag=0 then the program crashed.Other wise all but images changed

Comment: share your code on dropbox and give me link.. I will check and get back to you...

Comment: I don't know how to share in dropbox

Comment: @rams : okay... do one thing, use `myButton.tag = i+1000;` instead of `myButton.tag = i;` and tell me whether its working or not... for 0 its crashing because there are many UI on view that have tag as 0 which is default...

Comment: @rams : does it work with `myButton.tag = i+1000;`??

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/links , I am new one the code is totally confused don't get irritate with coding i learning  ok

Comment: @rams : what is this link? after you add zip file there is option called share.. click share and provide me the link that is generated by share...

Comment: In main view select photos, and we can see folders select any folder we can see pics and now select edit button we get alert then press ok after click any pic the pis is changed but we select first pic the program crashed please solve it

Comment: @rams : rams bhai, itni help nahi kar sakta yaar... jo bhi ho sakti thi ki maine...

Comment: Fahim Parkar thanks yar finally i got it just i changer tag value